# Extracting the date-redshift sql

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract the date from the field orderstatus ..Whenever the field orderstatus has the pattern *SLD in the beginning then the date in the orderstatus column needs to be extracted as the soldorstockdate else the orddate should be the soldorstockdate..

| orderstatus | orddate | Soldorstockdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *SLD 05/11/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 |
| 37141 SLD BAM | 5/5/2022 | 5/5/2022 |
| *SLD 5/14/22 Heman | 5/3/2022 | 5/14/2022 |
| 37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA | 5/18/2022 | 5/18/2022 |

The input columns are the orderstatus and orddate and the output column is soldorstockdate

Query tried:

```
select orderstatus,orddate ,  
case when CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(orderstatus,'S.*LD')<>0 
then COALESCE (DATE (TO_DATE (REGEXP_SUBSTR 
(orderstatus, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') || '/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')), orddate)  
 AS soldorstockdate
```

The DDL for the tables is below

```
Create table input
(orderstatus varchar(100),
orddate date)

insert into input values
('*SLD 05/11/2022','5/1/2022'),
('*SOLD 05/15/2022','5/8/2022'),
('37141 SLD BAM','5/5/2022'),
('*STOCK 05/16/2022','5/3/2022'),
('1277489 STK#39298.32831','5/4/2022')

create table output
(orderstatus varchar(100),
orddate date
soldorstockdate date) 

insert into output values
('*SLD 05/11/2022','5/1/2022','5/11/2022'),
('*SOLD 05/15/2022','5/8/2022','5/15/2022'),
('37141 SLD BAM','5/5/2022','5/5/2022'),
('*STOCK 05/16/2022','5/3/2022','5/16/2022'),
('1277489 STK#39298.32831','5/4/2022','5/4/2022')
```

****NOTE: I am trying to understand how to look for the pattern  * followed by SLD using redshift SQL****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to check the pattern `*SLD` in the beginning, You have to change your regular expression pattern to -

```
'^\*SLD'
```

Which will give you your desired result. Also, COALESCE inside the case statement will not work for null values. SO you have to update your select query to -

```
WITH DATA AS (SELECT '*SLD 05/11/2022' AS orderstatus FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT '37141 SLD BAM' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT '*SLD 5/14/22 Heman' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
              SELECT '37938 STOCK 5/18/22 PER SARA' FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(orderstatus,'^\*SLD') <> 0 
                 THEN TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(orderstatus, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}') || '/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                 ELSE orddate
       END AS soldorstockdate
  FROM DATA;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=01e2a25a4ecda27a8090d2240c0f4ff2)

Comment: Hi @ankit Bajpai..Appreciate your response!...I am getting the following error ..The database reported a syntax error: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression: '^*>>>HERE>>>SLD'. Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid preceding regular expression prior

Comment: SInce I do not have the Amazon redshift to test your code, So I have changed the DB to Oracle to test your code. You have to change the code as per Amazon redshift syntax. Only Matching Regular Expression needs to be same.

Comment: Hi Ankit....The change is just CASE WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(orderstatus,'^\\*SLD') <> 0